# How to write the query to search a string has different space in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, string, search, match

For example, the stored string could be '123456789', but the user might input '123 456 789' to search, or "1234 56789". How to handle the space in different location?
I use SQL Server2008 Express.

Answer (score 1):

You would use replace:

```
where str = replace(@str, ' ', '')
```

`@str` is the user input and `str` is the column inthe table.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how about if the stored string is "123 456 789", but user input is "123456789"?

Comment: @Russj, replace(str, ' ', '') = replace(@str, ' ', '') should take care of both the sides

Answer (score 1):

Can try using Trim function to remove white space from a field.

### select

```
SELECT  TRIM(fieldname)
,            LTRIM(fieldname)
,            RTRIM(fieldname)
,            LTRIM(RTRIM(fieldname))
FROM     tablename
```

### update

```
UPDATE
TableName
SET
ColumnName = LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnName))
```

TRIM() will remove both leading and trailing white spaces;
LTRIM() removes leading white spaces (i.e. from the beginning of a string);
RTRIM() removes trailing white space (i.e. from the end of a string);
If TRIM() is not supported, then LTRIM(RTRIM()) will achieve the same result.

`SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(YourColumn)) FROM YourTable`

For more information : [TRIM FUNCTION](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-trim.html)

Comment: How to trim spaces in the middle?